# How to add proofing( Auto text suggestion when typing ) in onlyoffice editor. If i type HW i need the suggestions of its full word(Hello world)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/advanced

How to add proofing( Auto text suggestion when typing ) in onlyoffice editor. If i type HW i need the suggestions of its full word(Hello world).

```
var docEditor = new DocsAPI.DocEditor("placeholder", {
    "documentType": "text",
    "height": "100%",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.e30.t-IDcSemACt8x4iTMCda8Yhe3iZaWbvV5XKSTbuAn0M",
    "type": "desktop",
    "width": "100%",
    ...
});
```